# IQueryable<T> from raw SQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 7, there is `DbSet.FromSql`, which seems to me that allows to create `IQueryable<>` from raw SQL. According to [the doc](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap#700-features):

> Raw SQL queries provides the `DbSet.FromSql` method to use raw SQL
>   queries to fetch data. These queries can also be composed on using
>   LINQ.

How to implement something similar in old LINQ to SQL?

Comment: 6 months and a team of 5 devs would be your best bet.

Comment: @BenRobinson I do not want to implement the whole EF7, just this small feature :) Or do you think this is so complex to implement?

Comment: I might be exaggerating a touch, but i was suggesting it is too complex a thing to ask as a stack overflow question.

Comment: @BenRobinson Maybe someone has already done it and open source it.