# SQL to IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have SQL text query. I not want to use linq, it will be complicated linq.

How to get IQueryable expression from my SQL string, which i can use in other linq queries? 
I want to get something like this:

```
public class ElementCount
{
   public int ElementID { get; set; }
   public int ElementCount { get; set; }
}

string sql = "<element count query>";

IQueryable<ElementCount> elementsCount = GetExpression(sql);

dbContext.Elements.Join(elementsCount ,element=>element.ID,elementCount=>elementCount.ElementID,
```

... etc or something other linq query

Comment: I think [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) might serve your purpose. I don't know if it is possible to get `IQueryable` from raw sql, but `SqlQuery` doesn't execute your query until enumerated. If what are you looking for is being able to call LINQ methods, you will be able to, because they have also `IEnumerable` overrides.

Comment: I tried. This does not work. SqlQuery return DbRawSqlQuery

Comment: Why exactly do you need `IQueryable`?

Comment: It's not exactly. I want to get expression which i can use in other linq to sql queries

Comment: Well, [I don't think it's possible if you're not using EF7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144330/iqueryablet-from-raw-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your query have to be defined in C#?

Because if not, you can always make it into a View or Stored Procedure in the DB and map that into your DbContext as an IQueryable.